# patch earlier versions of Android SDK

Tags: android, textview

I'm currently working on rendering CJK characters with custom `ReplacementSpan` in the `TextView`. While the line breaking strategy in the earlier versions of SDK (before API 22) has a minor issue and doesn't work the way we hope it does. How can I patch those SDKs to make my application work on older devices?

I've thought about subclassing `TextView` (and also `DynamicLayout` and `StaticLayout`) and then overriding all methods that should be modified. However, some of those methods are private or only visible within the package which means I can't override it.

**UPDATE**

I've tried subclassing `TextView`, `StaticLayout` and cloning many other classes. With the help of reflection, I still couldn't get it work because of Java's damn access control. There're endless private nested classes and classes that can only be accessed within the same package which means you must cloning them to your package to get everything work. I'm really tired of it.

Comment: Did you try implementing your own Layout? You can override TextView.makeNewLayout() and set your own implementation from there. Obviously with reflection.

Comment: @Zielony Thanks for your help. Yeah, I've just noticed that makeNewLayout() is a protected method, it would be the entry point. I'm starting right now. BTW, what do you mean by "with reflection"?

Comment: Layout mLayout in TextView is private and makeNewLayout doesn't return anything. To set that field you have to use Java Reflection API.

Comment: @Zielony Got it. I'm not familiar with Java and just knew that private members are not inherited. Thanks again for your help:)